# Remove dynamic generated string from string Jquery

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I have this html image with a source:

```
<img src="http://url/test/img-429x600.jpg" class="test-class">
```

What I need is, to remove the "-429x600" part from the source. I can achieve that using the following jquery:

```
var imgSrc = $('.test-class').attr("src");
imgSrc = imgSrc.replace("-429x600", "");    
$('.test-class').attr("src", imgSrc);
```

Now my problem is, how can I remove the same string but if I don't know the numbers that will appear there. I want to be able to remove that part of the string but without specifying the exact value.

https://jsfiddle.net/9hmyyrh3/

Comment: If it's always a .jpg, you could just chop off everything after the first X characters and append .jpg back onto it.

Comment: what is your src attr?

Comment: Ye, well the problem is that it can have other formats also, and the name of the image can have "-" characters in it as it can also have numbers so I can't basically remove numbers. :/

Comment: What do you mean? The original src attr?

Comment: yeah, value in src attribute

Comment: http://176.61.147.39/~adegamae/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/pintanegra_vinho21-429x600.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first take name and then extension, remove unwanted string

```
var abc = $('.test-class').attr("src");
var ext = abc.substr(abc.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
var name = abc.slice(0,-12);
var image_name = name+"."+ext;
$('.test-class').attr("src", image_name);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/farhanbaloch/9hmyyrh3/1/

Answer (score 1):

I broke this down into a step by step just to make it readable

```
var imgSrc = $('.test-class').attr("src");
var img = /[^/]*$/.exec(imgSrc)[0];
var newImg = img.replace(/-.*\./g, ".");
```

It strips the image name, looks for the "-STUFF." and replaces it with just "."

https://jsfiddle.net/2yngbx96/

**UPDATE:**
OK, a new version that takes into account a hyphen mid-name and uses the last hyphen as it's filter point

```
var imgSrc = $('.test-class').attr("src"); // get image src
var url = imgSrc.substring(0, imgSrc.lastIndexOf("/") + 1); // grab the base url
var img = /[^/]*$/.exec(imgSrc)[0]; // get the image name
var imgParts = img.split('.'); // seperate image to get extension
var imgName = /.*-/.exec(img)[0]; // get image name prior to last "-"
var newURL = url + imgName.substring(0,imgName.length - 1) + "." + imgParts[1]; // create new image url
$('.test-class').attr("src", newURL);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kf4xeeq1/

Comment: The only problem I've checked in your code is that if I have a "-" in the middle of the name of the image it will break the link

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks ;)